# How do you add Spock to IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, spock, intellij-14

I'm trying to get a simple "Hello World" Spock test set up in IntelliJ - can't seem to get it going. I have done the following:

- Downloaded and installed the plugin
- Selected the class name in the editor
- Navigated "Go-To" to "Test"
- "Create new test..."
- Selected Spock radio button

At this point, I get a "Spock library not found in the module" message below the radio buttons. There is no suggested solution here to install it. Is there some kind of Maven setup I need to do to the module? This was not necessary for Groovy setup, which did not need dependencies in Maven.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/GettingStarted Of course it's much simpler with a Gradle or Maven build.

Comment: That is not answering my question, but thanks.

Comment: Why not? The Getting Started Guide explains *exactly* how to set up Spock in IntelliJ, and also links to a sample Maven build. The IntelliJ plugin you refer to is totally optional.

Comment: Because that page describes downloading the jar etc. The Maven example might be in there somewhere, but I can't find it. Did find it elsewhere though so I'm set! And I hope this will help someone else in the future. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: But Peter is right, the Getting Started Guide **does** have a section "Ant/Gradle/Maven" which contains a link to a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example) with a full project containing build configs for all three tools. If you are unable to follow a link, don't be surprised that other people who volunteered to help you downvote you (I didn't, though).

Comment: That's tracing down three levels of link and digging into a pom file. Other sites just printed the dependency cleanly (which is what I was looking for, and what I put in my own answer). Thanks for the non-down-vote!

Comment: Newer repo for sample project(s): https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So....  What I needed to do, since I have maven, was add the following dependency and build:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spock-maven</artifactId>
     <version>0.7-groovy-2.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

If you just need it in IntelliJ, add a new library in Project Structure, and search the library.

Comment: `spock-maven` is a Maven plugin that's totally optional. First and foremost, you'll have to add a dependency on `spock-core`.

Comment: AFAIK *spock-maven* is not even compatible with Maven 3, so it is not a good idea to use it. But because *spock-maven* has a test dependency on *spock-core*, it may work in your specific environment. Are you still on Maven 2?

Answer (score 2):

`spock-core` only is required. Add this dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses Grails, go to buildConfig.groovy file and add the following changes: 
    repositories {
        .
        .

```
    mavenRepo "http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/"
    mavenRepo "http://m2repo.spockframework.org/snapshots/"
    .
    .

}

dependencies {
    .
    .       
    test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"
    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
    .
    .       
}

plugins {
    .
    .       
    test(":spock:0.7") {
        exclude "spock-grails-support"
    }

    compile ":jaxrs-spock:0.0.1-grails2.2"
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following to my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
</build>
```

otherwise IntelliJ did not automatically mark the groove dir as test directory.